# What does it mean for a GPS PRN to be unserviceable?

Tags: navigation, gnss, notam

There is a current NOTAM:

> !GPS 02/035 GPS Navigation PRN 28 unserviceable Feb 21, 2023 2020Z to May 31, 2023 2359Z

What exactly does it mean for a GPS PRN to be unserviceable, and what significance does it have for navigation?

Comment: https://www.gps.gov/technical/prn-codes/

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Seems like good info, but I think it assumes I know a few too many things I don't know.

Comment: Do you know anything about digital circuits?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPS (Navstar) usually has more satellites in view than are strictly necessary for navigation.   An IFR certified receiver has information to determine when the current computed position is within required specs based on which satellites are in view.   A handheld GPS for hiking may just fall back to an imprecise solution with no warning when insufficient satellites or poor geometry is all that is available.

The protocol used by the system allows up to 32 regular satellites (numbered PRN 1 through PRN 32) to transmit timing information to the receivers used for the location (and another few satellites can transmit WAAS updates).  But the minimum for global coverage is 24.  This means that most of the time, the loss of 1 or 2 satellites doesn't cause a problem.  Aviation users with a clear view of the entire hemisphere should have enough other satellites visible to give good solutions.  Unless there are other problems, I would expect the unavailable satellites to have no impact.

PRN Unserviceable means that this satellite can't be used by your receiver.  Your receiver already knows this.  Most receivers have a page that can display the current vehicles in view, and will display their PRN on the hemisphere relative to your position.

If you have some sort of advanced mission planning that needs to guarantee a specific precision available during an upcoming flight, you could use this information to predict what satellites would be visible, in what geometry, and what the likely precision might be at any point in the flight.  I'm not sure if anyone in civil aviation bothers.

Comment: So a PRN number essentially just refers to a fixed GPS satellite? Or do physical satellites switch around PRN numbers?

Comment: They can switch.  The PRN is a "logical" number that is reused as sats go into and out of service.  There is also a "SVN" (Space Vehicle Number) that is not reused and isn't limited to 1-32.   (Your receiver doesn't care about that number, just the PRN.)

Status page: https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/gps-constellation

Comment: I see, thanks. :)

Comment: You answer without even explaining what PRN stands for

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Having looked up what PRN stands for, it doesn't seem to add much to the answer. It could just as well stand for "Position Reporting Number" as "Pseudorandom Noise" for all the useful information that conveys. ;)

Comment: @Chris Arguably, [Gold sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_code) are one of the most interesting things about GPS. And why can't two satellites use the same Gold sequence if one of them has been decommissioned?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am interested in that kind of detail. Feel free to write your own answer! I just don't feel there is anything wrong with an answer that focuses on the practical aspects. Adding "PRN stands for pseudorandom noise" alone doesn't add much unless you add a lot more details to go with it.

Comment: For a good tutorial on GPS PRN codes, there's this series of [articles on Github](https://natronics.github.io/blag/2014/gps-viz-1/).

Comment: @Gerry Interesting stuff! But it ends on a cliffhanger. :(

Comment: These are great questions.  Perhaps ask them in another forum (space?  physics?) and I'll try to address (or in chat...).   But the gory details just didn't seem to be in-scope for Aviation..

Comment: oops. You're right. For some reason that page doesn't have a link at the bottom to the following article. [Here it is](https://natronics.github.io/blag/2014/gps-prn/). And that is followed by [this article](https://natronics.github.io/blag/2014/gps-spreading/).  There are also this [document](https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/sites/default/files/pdf/gps/GPSNAVSTARUsersOverviewMarch1991.pdf) at the USCG Navigation Center.